# Problemas con git clone

Tags: ubuntu, git, github, wsl, git-clone

Tengo un problema con git clone , cuando clono usando http :

```
git clone https://github.com/burbanox/responsive-design.git
```

Me tira el error :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/burbanox/responsive-design.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
```

Entonces cuando uso ssh :

```
git clone git@github.com:burbanox/responsive-design.git
```

Se queda cargando para siempre mostrando :

```
Cloning into 'responsive-design'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 115, done.
remote: Counting objects:   6% (7/115)
```

Uso ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Trate de compilar Openssl pero no funciono

Edit 1 :
Cuando corro :

```
GIT_TRACE=true git clone https://github.com/burbanox/responsive-design.git
```

La salida es :

```
21:06:19.094748 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git clone https://github.com/burbanox/responsive-design.git
Cloning into 'responsive-design'...
21:06:19.097019 run-command.c:666       trace: run_command: git remote-https origin https://github.com/burbanox/responsive-design.git
21:06:19.097955 git.c:743               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/burbanox/responsive-design.git
21:06:19.098016 run-command.c:666       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/burbanox/responsive-design.git
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/burbanox/responsive-design.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
```

Comment: Podrías intentar corriendo con `GIT_TRACE` y decirnos qué te dice editando la pregunta? `GIT_TRACE=true git clone bla blah` https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables

Comment: Que version de git estas usando? Y de paquetes de la distro?

Comment: git version 2.33.0 , y perdon no entiendo muy bien que son los paquetes de la distro?

Comment: Como instalaste git? Con `sudo apt install git`? O bajaste los fuentes y los compilaste?

Comment: Acabo de intentar hacer un clon de ese proyecto con el url `https://github.com/burbanox/responsive-design.git` (usando git 2.30.2 de paquetes de debian testing) y no tuve problemas... no estoy diciendo que lo que ves no es cierto, solo doy un poco de información.

Comment: Estás usando un proxy, por casualidad?

Comment: git lo instale usando ´sudo apt install git´ , y como podria saber si estoy usando un proxy ?

Comment: Si estás en tu casa, es poco probable (aunque se han visto casos). Si estás en un ambiente empresarial, es más probable... podrías ver tu configuración del browser o preguntarle a los administradores de red/sistemas.

Comment: No ya averigue y no estoy utilizando un proxy, crees que haya algo que bloquee la señal ?

Comment: No se me ocurre nada, la verdad.

Comment: Bueno en todo caso muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, aparentemente tenia bitTorrent instalado y creo que al parecer eso era lo que estaba bloqueando la aplicacion